# How to create self signed certifcates for 2 set of Statefulset's pods that are communicating with each other through service

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am trying to secure communication between Elasticsearch, Logstash, Filebeat, and Kibana. I have generated certificates as per this [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/configuring-ssl-tls-and-https-to-secure-elasticsearch-kibana-beats-and-logstash) using `x-pack` certutil, but when my `logstash` service is trying to communicate with `elasticsearch`'s data nodes service I am getting the following error:

> Host name 'elasticsearch' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=elasticsearch-data-2)"

I know this is a pretty common error and I have tried out multiple ways but unable to find a solution. I am confused about what `CN` and `SAN` I should provide so that all my data nodes, master nodes, logstash and kibana instances can communicate with each other.

PS: I have 1 statefulset(elasticsearch-data, elasticsearch-master) with one ClusterIP service(elasticsearch, elasticsearch-master) for each ES data node and master node.

Comment: the link to blog post is not working

Comment: @Maruf Tuhin please check now

Comment: Have You tried changing host name to match the CN? There exists an issue where host name and CN are same but don't work because of SAN overwrite. But in Your case the host name and CN in cert don't match.